# What is the best way to re-write (simplify) the same logic to produce the same result as below codes in R?

Tags: r

I need to extract a sample that has equal distribution in each experience-level group. For your info, there are total 4 groups (1, 2, 3, 4 years of exp), and total 8 people (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H) in this example scenario. I was trying to come up with a function with loops, but don't know how to. Please help me out! Thank you! :)

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(id = c("A","A","A","B","B","C","C","D","D","D","D","E","E","E","E","F","F","G","G","G","H","H","H","H"),year_exp = c(1,2,3,1,2,1,2,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4), pre_year_exp = year_exp - 1)

data_0 <- data %>% filter(year_exp == max(year_exp) - 0) %>% sample_n(2)
data_1 <- data %>% filter(year_exp == max(year_exp) - 1) %>% anti_join(data_0, by = 'id') %>% sample_n(2)
data_2 <- data %>% filter(year_exp == max(year_exp) - 2) %>% anti_join(data_0, by = 'id') %>% anti_join(data_1, by = 'id') %>% sample_n(2)
data_3 <- data %>% filter(year_exp == max(year_exp) - 3) %>% anti_join(data_0, by = 'id') %>% anti_join(data_1, by = 'id') %>% anti_join(data_2, by = 'id')

#Result Table
result <- data_0 %>% bind_rows(data_1, data_2, data_3)
result
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. If your code works as expected but you're just trying to improve it, the question is considered off topic here - but there is sibling project [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) that sounds more appropriate

Comment: Can you provide more information about your data and what you are trying to accomplish? Is your goal to take a random sample of 2 people from each group, sampling each person exactly once? Do you want to sample with equal probability? Your approach currently gives some people a much greater probability of being selected than others and would often throw an error if you started with max(year_exp) - 3 instead of max(year_exp) - 0.

Answer (score 0):

The below produces the same output as your code and extends the idea to allow for an arbitrary number of values of `year_exp` using a `for` loop.

Please note that because this simply extends your code, it must share the following (possibly-undesirable) features with your code:

- The code moves sequentially through groups, sampling from the members of later groups who were not sampled for early groups.  Accordingly, there is a risk that the code throws an error because it tries to sample from groups whose members were already sampled from previous, other groups.
- The probabilities of selection are not uniformly distributed across members of a group. Accordingly, the samples drawn from each group are not representative of that group.
- In the event that there data were instead a balanced panel, there are much more efficient and simpler ways to accomplish this.

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)

# Create original data
data <- tibble(id = c("A","A","A","B","B","C","C","D","D","D","D","E","E","E","E","F","F","G","G","G","H","H","H","H"),
                     year_exp = c(1,2,3,1,2,1,2,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4),
                     pre_year_exp = year_exp - 1)

# Assign values to parameters used by/in the loop.
J <- data$id %>% unique %>% length       # unique units/persons  (8)
K <- data$year_exp %>% unique %>% length # unique groups/years   (4)
N <- 2                                   # sample size per group (2)

# Initialize objects loop will modify
samples_list <- vector(mode = "list", length = K) # stores each sample
used_ids <- rep(NA_character_, J)                 # stores used ids
index <- 1:N                                      # initial indices for used ids

# For-loop solution
for (k in 1:K) {
  # Identifier for current group
  cur_group <- 1 + K - k 
  
  # Sample from persons in current group who were not previously sampled
  one_sample <- data %>%
    filter(year_exp == cur_group, !(id %in% used_ids)) %>%
    slice_sample(n = N)
  
  # Save sample and the id values for those sampled
  samples_list[[k]] <- one_sample
  used_ids[index] <- one_sample$id
  index <- index + N
}


# Bind into a single data.frame
bind_rows(samples_list)
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#>   id    year_exp pre_year_exp
#>   <chr>    <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1 H            4            3
#> 2 D            4            3
#> 3 G            3            2
#> 4 E            3            2
#> 5 C            2            1
#> 6 B            2            1
#> 7 F            1            0
#> 8 A            1            0
```